# Add a button to the Dynamics AX About screen

Tags: dialog, axapta

Anyone have some sample code for adding a button (with a click method popping up a dialog) to the About screen in Dynamics AX?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: click method popping up a dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The About screen in Dynamics AX is just a predefined form `SysAbout`.
You can just change that form.

Comment: Was using some instructions from the Microsft ISV packet that seemed to indicate everything was being created dynamically.  It said the button had to be added by editing the ApplicationVersion class.  Based on that, I assumed everything was dynamic and didn't even look for a form.

Thanks for your help.  This is an easy one now.  ;)